# Is there is a built-in method to sort a 2D array directly?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting, built-in

Is there is a built-in method in Java to sort a 2D array directly

For example: if I have an array of first name & phone number, can I sort it according to the first name while each name will keep it's phone number using built-in function?

Comment: could you give a more specific description of the data structure youre trying to sort? code would be good.

Comment: Why don't you go for TreeMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your data structure `[[name1, name2, ...], [phone1, phone2,...]]` or `[[name1, phone1], ...]`? If it's the latter, you can use a [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

```
class NameAndPhoneComparator implements Comparator<String[]> {
    public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
        int c = o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]);
        if (c != 0) return c;
        return o1[1].compareTo(o2[1]);
    }
}
```

Then use [Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5b%5d,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Answer (score 2):

Make your 2d Array into a 1D array of the below class, then use built in methods with a custom Comparator to do the sorting. You could also make this class [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) to itself.

```
class Person{
    public String name;
    public String phNumber;
}
```

Alternatively use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html),as sansix suggests, with the key as the name and value as phNumber. There would be no need for a comparator any more, and the Data will always be sorted.

Comment: But  by  this  the first name may lose his phone number and  get a random one